# NestJS: Control exit code on application shutdown?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Using `app.close()` to shut down a nestjs application gracefully, as per the NestJS docs.

However, when I call it, it returns an exit code of 1 as if there was an error.

How can I modify the exit code to `0` for a particular shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process core module provides a handy method that allows you to programmatically exit from a Node.js program: process.exit().

 When Node.js runs this line, the process is immediately forced to terminate.

This means that any callback that's pending, any network request still being sent, any filesystem access, or processes writing to stdout or stderr - all is going to be ungracefully terminated right away.

If this is fine for you, you can pass an integer that signals the operating system the exit code:

```
process.exit(0);
```

**Additions**
The process.exitCode property can be set to tell the process which exit code to use when the process exits gracefully. So instead of process.exit(0) you use:

```
process.exitCode = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this approach, but I'm wondering if I can call `process.exit(0)` AFTER `app.close()` so that I can wait for nestjs to shutdown gracefully prior to exit

Comment: i just updated the answer with a piece of code that gracefully shuts down the server.